# Laravel 5.1 finding project owner email with project_id in other table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to find a users email when I know the project id.

So in my table projects for example I have a record:
id: 1 user_id: 6

I know want to find the email of user 6 in my users table: for example:
id: 6 email: hello@gmail.com

so as a result I want to get hello@gmail.com

I've tried something like this, but doesn't seem to be working:

```
$projectOwnerEmail = DB::table('users')
        ->select('email')
        ->where('id', '=', $input['project_id'])
        ->join('projects', 'users.id', '=', 'projects.user_id')
        ->get();
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't just using `DB::table('users')->where('user_id', 6)`?

Comment: @user3158900 I'm guessing because the know ID here is the `project_id`, not the `user_id` as stated in the question :).

Comment: Yes exactly I only have access to the project_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you create using the Query Builder is the following:

```sql
SELECT email
FROM users
INNER JOIN projects ON users.id = projects.user_id
WHERE id = ?
```

The problem with this is that when evaluating the condition, there is no way to determine if you are trying to compare the `id` of the `users` table or the `id` of the `projects` table. This results in an integrity constraint violation error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

To fix this you just need to specify the table for the `id` column like so:

```
->where('projects.id', '=', $input['project_id'])
```

Also, using `get` will return a collection, which is ok because you can access the email like so `$projectOwnerEmail[0]->email`, but that feels overly complicated. Instead you can use `pluck` which will return a string with the email address instead:

```
$projectOwnerEmail = DB::table('users')
    ->select('email')
    ->where('projects.id', '=', $input['project_id'])
    ->join('projects', 'users.id', '=', 'projects.user_id')
    ->pluck('email');
```

Now you have the email string stored directly in the `$projectOwnerEmail` variable.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed explenation! I learned so much! Amazing!